# Autoplay incoming WebRTC stream on chrome on android

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I have a multi peer WebRTC stream using simple-peer and I'm playing the received stream like this:

```
        peer.on("stream", data => {
          let audio = document.createElement("audio") as HTMLAudioElement;
          audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(data);
          audio.play();
        });
```

This works fine on desktop but for chrome on android there is no sound:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: play() can only be initiated by a user gesture.
```

I couldn't find any documentation on how to correctly play the received stream. Do I really have to show a button when the stream is ready?

I have also tried to work around this issue by playing the stream from getUserMedia but this only worked as long as I didn't call `audioTag.muted = true` which is no solution either because this creates a feedback loop.

```
let audioTag = document.createElement("audio") as HTMLAudioElement;
audioTag.autoplay = true;

navigator.getUserMedia({video: false, audio: true}, (async stream => {
  audioTag.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  audioTag.muted = true;
  // ...
});
```

Sites like http://talky.io seem to have found a way around this problem though, so what do I have to do?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but mobile devices require the user to press the play button of audio/video streams in order it to play. Not sure about the workaround.

Comment: I have the same question. https://whereby.com does also play audio without user interaction, so there has to be a workaround somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: https://www.chromium.org/audio-video/autoplay

```
var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();

if (promise !== undefined) {

  promise.then(_ => {

    // Autoplay started!

  }).catch(error => {

    // Autoplay was prevented.

    // Show a "Play" button so that user can start playback.

  });

}
```